# How to type zero-width space character (U+200B) on a laptop keyboard?

Tags: windows, keyboard, unicode

There is a very similar question to this one already ([How can I type U+200B character?](https://superuser.com/questions/156640/how-can-i-type-u200b-character)) but all the answers are about how to type this character on a PC keyboard with a num pad which is not my case.

I use Czech (QWERTY) layout but am willing to switch to English (US) layout if necessary.

How do I type this character (U+200B) on a laptop keyboard without a num pad?

**Edit**: I want to do this on Windows, without a Fn key if possible. If the process of "typing" it involves MS Word, copy/paste from some website or anything else that is easily doable on a standard Windows laptop, I'm fine with that too.

Comment: What operating system? Also, you may be able to use `Fn` to get a keypad keys.

Comment: Edited a question, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I type U+200B character?](https://superuser.com/questions/156640/how-can-i-type-u200b-character)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could just use the Character Map program, built into Windows. It lists all characters for each font installed on the system, and lets you select one and copy it to the clipboard. In fact, I use it to reference all the keycodes to type them, otherwise, but when I'm on my laptop, it's handy just to be able to copy the characters from that program.

It's available in the Accessories start group, or by running `charmap.exe`.

You can copy `U+200B` like so:

[image: charmap]

Comment: How about `U+200F`? It doesn't appear to list that. :/

Comment: @TomWijsman It depends on the font. Arial Unicode MS doesn't have it, but (for example) Calibri does.

Comment: Ah, interesting, thank you! +1 Didn't know one could get the characters there...

Comment: Missing in this answer is how to actually find the character: Activate advanced view and use the input field labelled "Go to Unicode" or just "Unicode" in newer versions. Input `200B` and the character will be selected in the top left corner. Searching for the name only works if you know how the character is called in your locale.

Comment: This inserted a line break when I pasted it.

Answer (score 6):

1. [Alt code on Laptop Keyboard](http://alt-codes.org/laptop/) - This works *if* your keyboard have a numlock key. *If not* try this:
2. Use the osk.exe utility (the Visual Keyboard) typically in `C:\windows\system32\osk.exe`

   - Click on *options* on the Visual keyboard
   - Check the option "*activate the numeric pad*"
   - Press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key on the "real" keyboard *AND* enter the Alt-code on the Visual Keyboard
   - Then *release* the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key on the "real" keyboard

The character must be written on notepad or any other application.

Here a screen capture : alt code 0128 in Notepad++:

[image: screen capture : alt code 0128 in Notepad++]

Hope this help. Let us know.

Answer (score 6):

I have written a small application for just this purpose! It is called **Npad**, and it is a simple [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com) script to conditionally remap the normal number keys to behave as the Numpad keys. This allows you to enter Unicode characters using their <kbd>Alt</kbd> keystroke combinations with **any** keyboard.

### Instructions:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to **toggle** Npad between `0` and `1`, off and on respectively.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to display the **state** of Npad without toggling on or off.

### Source:

<sub>Note: See the download link below for the latest version...</sub>

```
npad = 0

^#n:: ;Ctrl+Win+N
npad := !npad
MsgBox, , Npad, Toggle: %npad%
Exit

!#n:: ;Alt+Win+N
MsgBox, , Npad, State: %npad%
Exit

#If (npad)
    0::Numpad0
    1::Numpad1
    2::Numpad2
    3::Numpad3
    4::Numpad4
    5::Numpad5
    6::Numpad6
    7::Numpad7
    8::Numpad8
    9::Numpad9
#If
Exit
```

---

**Download:** https://bitbucket.org/iglvzx/npad/downloads

Comment: sweet, gonna use this a lot.

Comment: Nice although I would appreciate a solution that doesn't involve running a 3rd party utility and pressing like 15 keys to insert one freaking character :) Nothing against this solution, I appreciate your effort, I was just hoping for a simpler solution if there's any.

Comment: @Borek If you don't want to memorize Alt codes, see **sidran32**'s answer below. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is probably some way to simulate the numpad keys using normal keys. The manual of the system should tell you which function key or other tool needs to be used to enable such simulation and which keys are to be used for numpad keys.

But things get somewhat awkward then.

So perhaps a better approach is to download and install some nice utility, like [UnicodeInput](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/unicodeinput/) (for entering characters by Unicode number) or [unicode-input-by-name](http://code.google.com/p/unicode-input-by-name/) (for entering characters by their formal Unicode name). Unfortunately, for  both of them, the most conveniently way to launch the program is to type Alt++ using the numpad “+” key

Answer (score 1):

As I'm already a user of [ClipX](http://bluemars.org/clipx/), there is another way:

- Copy a zero width space character to a clipboard e.g. from [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) (if you're precise enough you will be able to select the character in the middle of any "Antidisestablishmentarianism​Antidisestablishmentarianism" combination, if not copy it to MS Word, show hidden characters and copy from there)
- In ClipX, install the Stickies plugin (try icon > Configure > More Plugins)
- In the Stickies plugin page in the configuration window, click "add", select "from current history" and select the weird character (it displayed like `€;&` or something like that)

You'll then be able to insert this character anywhere by invoking ClipX (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> by default) and selecting the sticky you just created.

To test that it works properly, you can use MS Word or some other text editor that can count characters or display the hidden ones.

Works great for me!